# Change the font size of text annotation inside ggplotly object

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I have the dataframe below:

```
df <- data.frame(result=floor(rnorm(1000, 100, 20)))
```

and I create a ggplotly histogram with an annotation. I would like to know how to change the font size inside `paste()`.

```
require(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(result=floor(rnorm(1000, 100, 20)))   
ggplotly(ggplot(df)+
  geom_histogram(aes(result, fill = (result<=80 | result > 95)),
                 binwidth = 5, center = 2.5, color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkblue", "lightblue"), guide = F) +
  labs(y = "Frequency", x = "Result") + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)+
  theme_classic(base_size = 16))%>%
  layout(annotations = list(x = 140, y = 100, text = paste("Mean:","Num"), showarrow = T))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this answer to fix this https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/